# PIXI.Layers + PIXI.Particles

Tags: javascript, game-development, pixi.js

How to set layer for particles while using layers?
For now all particles under other objects, but parent container for particles above all objects.

Thank you

https://github.com/pixijs/layers
Here exists information about particles:

```
import { ParticleContainer } from 'pixi.js';
import { applyCanvasMixin } from '@pixi/layers';

applyParticleMixin(ParticleContainer);
```

I used it for container, which сontains particles, but its not help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.